# retrieve x and y value based on graph in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution

I'm new in r and I would ask you all some help. I have x (value) and prob (it's probability) as follow:

- x <- c(0.00, 1.08, 2.08, 3.08, 4.08, 4.64, 4.68)
- prob <- c(0.000, 0.600, 0.370, 0.010, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006)

My aim is to contruct an estimate distribution graph based on those values. So far, I use `qplot(x,prob,geom=c("point", "smooth"),span=0.55)` to make it and it's shown here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVgNk.png

my question are:

1. Are there any other ways to contruct a nice distribution like that
   without using qplot?
2. I need to retrieve the all the x values (i.e., 0.5, 1, 1.2, etc) and their corresponding prob values. Can can I do that?

I've been searching for a while, but with no luck.

Thank you all

Comment: do you want to estiamte what distribution they come from? although the stats wont be very good as you have very few observations

Comment: Yes Jan.... I would love to know what is the distribution it is given limited data like that. But I don't know how to do it? Or even is it possible given that limited of data?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to predict the values of `prob` for given values of `x`, this is one way to do it. Note I'm using a `loess` prediction function here (because I believe it's the default for `ggplot`'s `smooth` geom, which you've used), which may or may not be appropriate for you.

```
x <- c(0.00, 1.08, 2.08, 3.08, 4.08, 4.64, 4.68)
prob <- c(0.000, 0.600, 0.370, 0.010, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006)
```

First make a data frame with one column, I'll put a whole lot of data points into that column, just to make a bunch of predictions.

```
df <- data.frame( datapoints = seq.int( 0, max(x), 0.1 ) )
```

Then create a prediction column. I'm using the `predict` function, passing a `loess` smoothed function to it. The `loess` function is given your input data, and `predict` is asked to use the function from `loess` to predict for the values of `df$datapoints`

```
df$predicted <- predict( loess( prob ~ x, span = 0.55 ), df$datapoints )
```

Here's what the output looks like.

```
> head( df )
  datapoints  predicted
1        0.0 0.01971800
2        0.1 0.09229939
3        0.2 0.15914675
4        0.3 0.22037484
5        0.4 0.27609841
6        0.5 0.32643223
```

On the plotting side of things, `ggplot2` is a good way to go, so I don't see a reason to shy away from `qplot` here. If you want more flexibility in what you get from `ggplot2`, you can code the functions more explicitly (as @Jan Sila has mentioned in another answer). Here's a way with `ggplot2`'s more common (and more flexible) syntax:

```
plot <- ggplot( data = df, 
                mapping = aes( x = datapoints, 
                               y = predicted ) ) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth( span = 0.55 )
plot
```

Comment: Thank you rosscova... The graph looks nice. However, I was wondering what is the explanation behind it? Does the code is trying to fit to another distribution?

Comment: The code is creating a prediction function using the loess smoothing method, then using that function to "predict" the missing values in the series.

Comment: However, why the cumulative probability of predicted prob is more than 1?
I did, max(cumsum(df$prob)/100) and get its maximum  value of more than 1. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The cumulative sum is greater because you've added more points by interpolation. Say you've got 2 points, each with a 0.5 probability, and you add a third point in between by "smoothing". The third point will of course be 0.5, so the `cumsum` will be 1.5. You shouldn't be trying to do that, probabilities don't work that way.

Comment: If what you're looking to do is break up a binned distribution into smaller parts, you'll need to normalise to force the `cumsum` to equal 1. You could do this by adding a step `df$predicted<-df$predicted/sum(df$predicted)`. That should "normalise" the distribution in the way you're hoping.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation explanation @rosscova, I'm sorry that my understanding of probability is not mature yet.

I just realize that what was write as:
prob <- c(0.000, 0.600, 0.370, 0.010, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006)
shoud be :
relative_frequency <- c(0.000, 0.600, 0.370, 0.010, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006)
I thought relative frequency would be the same as probability. 

So in the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVgNk.png), the Y-axis supposed to be a relative frequency. Having Y-Axis as a relative frequency, would the graph of its probabilty density function be same?

Comment: You're on the right track. You might want to do a search and/or pose a new question, perhaps on Cross Validated.

Comment: Sorry @rosscova to get back to you again as I was unable to look for the solution in this line of code.
df$predicted <- predict( loess( prob ~ x, span = 0.55 ), df$datapoints)
It produce a warning as follow:
Warning messages:
1: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :  span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.

At first, I ignored as it still produce predicted datapoints. But, as I run a script through command line by using "Rscript file_name.r", the execution stops at this line. I was wondering why does it happen?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the observations once you specify the probability distribution.[Have a look here](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiY5JuB98PRAhVLuBQKHe3ICxMQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv064i04%2Fv64i04.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFbYPChRiICWkyMeeLKckaBKJmGAw). This will help you and walk you through `MASS` package.

..nicer graphs? I think ggplot is the best (also pretty sure that grapgh is from ggplot2). IF you want exacatly that, then you want a blue `geom_line` and on top of that add `geom_point` with the same mapping :) Try to have  alook at tutorials, or we can help you out with that.