# Weighting Points along an 'S' curve in R

Tags: r

I have data in an R data frame and want to weight one column (`days_since`) along an S-curve (logit curve). Particularly, a backwards S-curve such that more recent events will be weighted more. My reasoning for using this curve as a weighting function is that it will heavily weight recent events as well as lightly weight distant events. Thus, I would like to write a function that for a give number of observations I could create an S-curve that provides the weights, such that as in the image below, the weights would be on the y-axis and the days since would be on the x-axis.

[Please ignore the points and labels on this graph, I was able to use the model of a reverse s-curve/logit function from another stackoverflow question].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This builds upon an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41660145/3019627) provided to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659903/retrieve-x-and-y-value-based-on-graph-in-r).

You can create the curve using a formula of your own or the sigmoid function from the `e1071` package, and the `curve()` function. Then, predict the values along the curve for given days in your dataset.

Here's a simple example.

```
library(scales)
library(e1071)

# Data set with points of interest. Suppose these are days. 
days <- data.frame( d = seq.int( 1, 365, 1 ) )
```

The `curve()` function will create x and y coordinates for your S-curve.

```
p <- invisible(curve(-sigmoid(x) , -6,6))
```

Rescale x and y to ensure the range contains your data values of interest. You will want to be able to predict y from x later. Rescaling y to upper and lower bounds will set upper and lower thresholds for your weights.

```
x <- rescale(p$x, to = c(1, 365))
y <- rescale(p$y, to = c(0,1))
```

Next, predict the values on the curve for your data of interest. In this example, days go from 1 to 365. You'll feed the `loess()` function to `predict()`. The `loess()` function will fit the curve surface (setting span to 0.1 will minimize any smoothing).

```
days$pred <- predict( loess( y ~ x, span=.1 ), days$d ) 

plot(days$d,days$pred)
```

Your weights are now in days$pred.

Comment: It's useful to link to previous answers to related questions, well done. Aside: the correct syntax to create a link is `[text](url)`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. This is a little code I use often to create fake data with seasonal effects. Hope others find it useful.