# R weighted mean with gaussian distribution

Tags: r, statistics

Limited stats education, so possibly am trying to define something that is a simple function, or why I am unable to find an existing answer

The problem is to calculate a weighted mean for a time series, with greater weight to the most recent data. The weighting should follow "one side of a gaussian curve" function ("S" curve?), highest value starting from the most recent (last) point. I realise there would be a couple coefficients to define the gradient of the curve, but assume "normal"

[Weighting Points along an 'S' curve in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958644/weighting-points-along-an-s-curve-in-r)

This seems to be asking the same question, but the only answer is a bit over-engineered for what I am looking for

I can generate a linear weighted average as follows

```
# time series data
d <- c(7, 8, 10, 7, 8, 11, 9, 6, 13, 10, 11, 11)
# weight coefficients
w <- seq(1, length(d), 1)
w <- w / sum(w)
w
[1] 0.01282051 0.02564103 0.03846154 0.05128205 0.06410256 0.07692308 0.08974359 0.10256410
[9] 0.11538462 0.12820513 0.14102564 0.15384615
weighted.mean(d, w, na.rm = T)
[1] 9.846154
```

How do I use a "gaussian sequence" for `w` instead of my linear one?

Comment: For an S-shaped curve, you may want something like a logistic distribution rather than Gaussian (bell-shaped).

Comment: thanks @zephryl, I can experiment with either. as long as the initial and final gradient is less steep than the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get weights that follow the left-hand side of a normal distribution like this:

```r
w <- dnorm(seq(-3, 0, length = length(d)))
w <- w / sum(w)
```

So the weights look something like this:

```
plot(w)
```

[image]

If you want the curve to be steeper, you can set the `sd` argument of `dnorm` to less than 1, and if you want it more gradual, increase its value. At the moment the example shows the default, with sd = 1.

---

**EDIT**

An alternative that might allow for better control would be a logistic curve:

```r
w <- plogis(seq(-1, 1, length = length(d)), scale = 0.3)
w <- w / sum(w)
plot(w)
```

[image]

```r
w <- plogis(seq(-1, 1, length = length(d)), scale = 0.15)
w <- w / sum(w)
plot(w)
```

[image]

Comment: All true.  But the solution also assumes that the observations are equally spaced.  This *may* not be true in the general case.  To use a distribution other than Normal, replace `dnorm` with the appropriate `dxxxx` function.  Each will have a different set of parameters to control the steepness of the slope.  **Also, don't forget to normalise the weights so that they sum to 1 to get a valid weighed average.**

Comment: @Limey good points. I have updated to specifically normalise the weights, as they were in the OP's question. The OP did mention that this was a time series, so for the purposes of this answer I thought a regular spacing could be assumed (the native `ts` class only allows regular spacing, though I know irregularly spaced time series can be used in extension packages). A logistic curve might actually be a better option, and I will include that in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks both. This is exactly what I was looking for. I've used ```w <- dnorm(seq(-3, 0, length = length(d))); w <- w / sum(w)``` following my linear answer, in order to normalise the coefficients. instead of dividing by ```dnorm(0)```

Answer (score 1):

To run a weighted mean along a time series, I would recommend using `convolve` for efficiency reason, rather than trying to reimplement it. For instance:

```r
d <- c(7, 8, 10, 7, 8, 11, 9, 6, 13, 10, 11, 11)

k <- dnorm(seq(-2,2, length.out = 5))

convolve(d, k/sum(k), type = "filter")


[1]  9.466427  7.427122  8.213693 10.465371  8.894341  7.066883 11.933909
[8] 10.425011
```